# extract blocks of text from xml file with a condition

Tags: text-processing, xml

I want to extract the contents of `fqdns` from the following file, but only for each `device` where `status` is `new`:

```xml
<device id='10.72.48.215'>
    <address>10.72.48.215</address>
    <status>old</status>
    <fqdns>10.72.48.215</fqdns>
    <parent></parent>
    <type>Unknown</type>
    <ports>
    </ports>
    <operatingsystems>
    </operatingsystems>
</device>
<device id='10.72.48.216'>
    <address>10.72.48.216</address>
    <status>new</status>
    <fqdns>10.72.48.216</fqdns>
    <parent></parent>
    <type>Unknown</type>
    <ports>
    </ports>
    <operatingsystems>
    </operatingsystems>
</device>
```

So, for the above, I want to obtain `10.72.48.216` (and not `10.72.48.215`).

Comment: Can you provide the output you want to extract from this xml file? I don't understand which part you mean.

Comment: I do not understand it too,

Comment: so basically, i have this long xml file with the same contents as above. some have "<status>old</status>" some has "new". But i just want to grab the "new" one. " <status>new</status>
                <fqdns>10.72.48.151</fqdns>
                <status>new</status>
                <fqdns>10.72.48.152</fqdns>
                <status>new</status>
                <fqdns>10.72.48.153</fqdns>" something like so

Comment: Your example has only  old ones.

Comment: pcregrep -M "\<status.*\n.*fqdns\>$" file.xml

Comment: Thxs Rui, this works. Can you explain the syntax a little bit for me? I not really good with this txt manipulation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add an XML declaration and enclose the two `device` elements in a top-level element, you can process your file with XPath:

```
$ cat ./248127.xml
    <device id='10.72.48.215'>
            <address>10.72.48.215</address>
            <status>old</status>
            <fqdns>10.72.48.215</fqdns>
            <parent></parent>
            <type>Unknown</type>
            <ports>
            </ports>
            <operatingsystems>
            </operatingsystems>
    </device>
    <device id='10.72.48.216'>
            <address>10.72.48.216</address>
            <status>new</status>
            <fqdns>10.72.48.216</fqdns>
            <parent></parent>
            <type>Unknown</type>
            <ports>
            </ports>
            <operatingsystems>
            </operatingsystems>
    </device>

$ ( echo '<?xml version="1.0"?><doc>'; cat ./248127.xml ; echo '</doc>' ) \
    | xpath -q -e '//device[status/text()="new"]/fqdns'
<fqdns>10.72.48.216</fqdns>
```

Comment: Toby, how i have both "old" and "new" status in the file. How do I just get the "new" one?

Comment: Modify the XPath expression appropriately - e.g. `xpath -q -e '//device[status/text()="new"]/fqdns'`

Comment: thxs this also works

Answer (score 1):

A simple **grep** can do the trick:

```
grep -A1 "<status>new" sample.xml 
# <status>new</status>
# <fqdns>10.72.48.216</fqdns>
```

which is only recommendet if the source of your xml is stable and doesn't change the order of lines. (I modified your example to have a 'new' in the second block.)

You may filter the following line with more grep:

```
grep -A1 "<status>new" sample.xml | grep "<fqdns>" 
# <fqdns>10.72.48.216</fqdns>
```

With **sed**, you can easily extract just the IP:

```
sed -rn '/<status>new/{n; s/.*<fqdns>(.*)<\/fqdns>/\1/p}' sample.xml
# 10.72.48.216
```

It matches `<status>new` and reads the **n**ext line and **s**ubstitutes `<fqdns>` and the end tag with the part in betweeen. The **-n** tells sed to 'no printing by default', the '-r' is to allow regular expressions, here the parens around .*, to be written without masking.

Comment: This is awesome. this is exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a pcrgrep command, which has an option for multiline search.

```
pcregrep -M "\<status.*\n.*fqdns\>$"
```

As for the explanation you requested:

So -M for multiline

\< status for the beggining of string. I have to use \ to take the meaning out of < as it is special to the shell.

Then . (any character) followed by * with it means it can be repeated.

\n for a new line

. for a character followed by * as it can be repeated.

then the string fqdns

and to close

\> which again is >, with \ to take the meaning

and finally, $ is the end of line

The strings matching is know as regexp

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: You are welcome. Please peruse the wikipedia entry to be able to build your own regexp expressions.